# Creating a Generic Object Factory

Tags: java, architecture

While developing an application i am struck in a case where not clear how should i proceed.My Application is not a very big implimentation so don't want to add any DI container (Spring/ Guice).

I have my Controler layer from where i need to call my service layer and i have two ways to create an instance of ServiceObject.

1. use simple `new` operator.
2. Create a factory layer.

i am aware about the factory pattern, but my intention is to create a generic ObjectFactory which should be capable enough to create and inject the given object.

Something similar to what Spring does (not that much) like exposing some setter method in my controller class and let that factory inject the specified object in that.

Any starting pointer in this regard will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Application is not a very big implimentation so don't want to add
>   any DI container (Spring/ Guice)

I think your applications size is not something you should not take into account (provided it's really not a HelloWolrd :)). As **artbristol** said the point in using an already existing framework is that you won't make the mistakes in your own implementation that others already did **and solved** later. I don't know if you have practical Spring knowledge (but we already know you are familiar with the concept behind very well) so i advise you to have a look at some of the basic tutorials on the topic and you will see how easy you can start using Spring.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just use Spring or Guice, whichever you're more familiar with. They're both really quite lightweight, and other people will be able to understand your application more easily than if you roll you own dependency injection. Your own implementation will eventually end up looking like one of them, but with less functionality and more bugs.

Comment: i am agree with that,but since application is small, say 10 Service classes so i don't want to add extra depedencies.Spring is not in my list due to licence issue :(

Comment: Spring has a very permissive licence, and Maven makes it very easy to bundle dependencies into your app. If you insist on rolling your own, just expose setter methods, and 'wire' all your 'beans' in one go, on application startup. This will allow you to add Spring later on with minimal changes.